# Bibtex citestyle not changing to author year, and capitalisation?

Tags: biblatex

I am trying- unsuccessfuly- to get a references list labelled by authoryear as in the [alpha sample here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Bibtex_bibliography_styles).

I'm really not sure how to show a sample of my output without just putting in a screenshot. But What I am getting in the references section is:

```
    References
Tsankov, T. The Minimal Flows of $S_\infty$. Logic, Dynamics, and Their Interactions, Denton. 2012.
```

And I am looking for

```
        References
[Tsa12] Tsankov, T. The Minimal Flows of $S_\infty$. Logic, Dynamics, and Their Interactions, Denton. 2012.
```

i.e. it is just the label that is missing in the references list. To be clear, the in-text citation works just fine, and if I omit the 'style' or 'bibstyle' specification in 
`\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=authoryear, citestyle=alphabetic]{biblatex}`
 (see code below) I get a numeric indexing as expected. It also works correctly if I specify 'bibstyle = numeric'.

I have used

```
     \usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=authortitle, citestyle=alphabetic]{biblatex}
```

And also tried replacing 'bibstyle' with 'style' in the above, with no success. The full control code is here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{a4wide}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=authortitle, citestyle=alphabetic]{biblatex}


\addbibresource{ref.bib}

\title{\textbf{dighj}}
\author{\textbf{fkgk:} dshjf \\ \textbf{Supervisor:} drjfdmj}
\date{}


\begin{document}
\maketitle
Testing here a \cite{topdyn} to see what comes out
\subfile{introduction.tex}


\printbibliography

\subfile{AppendixA.tex}

\end{document}
```

with the references in `ref.bib` the relevant portion of which is

```
@misc{topdyn,
    author = {T. Tsankov},
    title = {The Minimal Flows of S_\infty},
    howpublished = {Logic, Dynamics, and Their Interactions, Denton},
    year={2012}
}
```

Comment: Off-topic: `title = {The Minimal Flows of S_\infty},` looks like an error waiting to happen, use `title = {The Minimal Flows of {$S_\infty$}},` instead (the braces are needed when you use a style that applies sentence case.)

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand what you would like to see. If it is something similar to `alpha`, `style=alphabetic,` would be the way to go, but you seem to want something slightly different. Can you create a mock-up of what you would like to see in the bibliography and citations?

Comment: @moewe in fact, that part works just fine! I have elaborated on the error which shows that the problem isn't in the title formatting

Comment: Have you tried `\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}`? If so, what don't you like about it?

Comment: @moewe That solved the problem, thank you! I think I understand now what 'citestyle' and 'bibstyle' were doing

Answer (score 1):

You apparently want

```
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
```

`citestyle` controls the citation style, `bibstyle` controls the bibliography style. With `style` you can set `citestyle` and `bibstyle` at the same time. That is what people usually want. That's why I recommend to use `style` as much as possible and use `bibstyle` and `citestyle` only if absolutely necessary.